# Standards for marking questions as duplicates?

Tags: discussion

### EDIT:

It's ironic that this question itself got marked as a duplicate... and understandably so because in this case I suppose I didn't make it clear that the title was in fact the question of the post: Are there standards for marking questions as duplicates and if not should there be?

StackOverflow has grown to the point that there are often 3 people waiting at the gate to police your question the moment it arrives. Often, if you challenge anything they do they will say they're trying to help you even though they don't actually offer any useful information or improve your question in any way. That's why I think it would be nice to have some kind of standards for things like this to point them to.

---

It seems to me like if you're going to mark something as a duplicate, then you should actually be able to use the answer in one of the 'possible duplicate' posts as an answer to the post you're marking as a duplicate (provided they have accepted answers).

Case in point: I recently posted a question about how to open a link in a new window with 'just' the href attribute of an anchor link. I pointed out two important pieces of information in my post: 1) I actually already knew how to do it... just not without changing the current page and 2) I NEEDED to do it with the href attribute only; not because I wanted to or thought it was a good idea but because of constraints in the system I'm working with.

I looked for an answer on this site as well as googling but didn't find one. What I found was that it's bad practice to do what I wanted to do... so of course it's going to be hard to find people explaining how to do it the way I needed to do it. That's why I took time to explain why I needed to do it this way; otherwise I knew the answers I would get back would be everything but what I needed to see.

In my opinion, the words 'possible duplicate' don't mean 'possibly similar, but different'. They mean that the answer(s) to other questions may actually answer your question. If you can rule out all the answers on the 'possible duplicates' as not being able to answer the question you're marking then it's not a duplicate.

Right? Am I taking crazy pills here? I feel like I am.

EDIT: Oh yeah, I sort of forgot to finish the part about how my question was marked as a duplicate and the person who did it explained to me that the question had been asked many times. This was great news to me because I could look at the questions he pointed to for my answer!!! Except none of them answered my question and you could clearly see that the requirements of my question ruled all of them out upfront. :(

Comment: For completeness' sake: some users actually complain theirs is not a duplicate because *it uses different numbers!!!* -- or text strings, file names,  or variable and function names.

Comment: @Jongware Hence the question about whether a document explaining what a duplicate is and isn't would be useful since many don't seem to understand what seems like common sense to others of us.

Comment: One close vote does not close your question. And it wasn't necessary to put in large print: "For those who actually read this post (or even just read the title), you will know that this is not a duplicate of any question on this site (least not that can be found through reasonable searches)." Honestly, this question seems like a rant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860864/how-to-open-a-window-in-new-tab-with-just-href-attribute) is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab). You also made it clear in the question that the method used in the so-called duplicate does not work for the `href` attribute.

It appears the user probably misunderstood your question. Anyways it's only a single close vote, you will need 5 of them for your question to be marked as a duplicate (unless the voter has a gold badge on the subject).

Comment: I don't even care about the close vote. It's just that every time I post a question somebody has to come along and mark it as a possible duplicate about 60 seconds after I posted it. Either people yell at me for not providing enough information (even when I've provided all the necessary info, proven by the fact that someone answers my question w/o having to guess at anything I didn't say) or else I go through the effort to be extra clear and they mark my question as a dupe not even bothering to actually read the details of the question.

Comment: Basically, all the people who are more interested in policing this site than actually answering questions (but act like they are doing you a service if you challenge them) are really getting annoying.